# Alternative to MS Detours (32 bit)

Tags: c++, function-hooking

I have used MS Detours for one project in c++ and work perfectly.

I have created a clone of this application (95% of the some code) to hook another file (a GOG game with DRM free), but this time crash always on DetourAttach.

I have compared A/B these 2 projects (both are 32 bit) and for now seem that the new game that I need to hook is incompatible with detuors (or this is my impression).

I ask if there is a good alternative when detours not work.

Comment: This project may help https://github.com/wbenny/DetoursNT